How to override Spring Bean supplied from 3rd party dependency
The main idea is to override one method of the class from
I have an AwsSpringWebRuntimeInitializer class supplied by aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3. It implements ApplicationContextInitializer to register a specific bean (AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop) on application startup. This class is registered via the spring.factories file.
public class AwsSpringWebRuntimeInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AwsSpringWebRuntimeInitializer.class);
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
        logger.info("AWS Environment: " + System.getenv());
        Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("AWS Environment: " + System.getenv());
        }
        
        if (context instanceof ServletWebServerApplicationContext && isCustomRuntime(environment)) {
            if (context.getBeanFactory().getBeanNamesForType(AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop.class, false, false).length == 0) {
                context.registerBean(StringUtils.uncapitalize(AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop.class.getSimpleName()),
                        SmartLifecycle.class, () -> new AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop((ServletWebServerApplicationContext) context));
            }
        }
    }
    
    private boolean isCustomRuntime(Environment environment) {
        String handler = environment.getProperty("_HANDLER");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(handler)) {
            handler = handler.split(":")[0];
            logger.info("AWS Handler: " + handler);
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(handler);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Will execute Lambda in Custom Runtime");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}

What I need to do is to change one method in AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop. But this class also implements SmartLifecycle, which means it will be invoked on startup.
public final class AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop implements SmartLifecycle

I've tried to exclude the whole AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop and replace it with my counterpart. I also tried to replace this bean by registering a new bean with the same name (using custom ApplicationContextInitializer), but it's invoked before the AwsSpringWebRuntimeInitializer, so that bean was overridden by one created by AwsSpringWebRuntimeInitializer. However, the main problem is that the AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop class starts on the start of the application, so changing context in the main method after the app was up is useless.
Is there any way to replace AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop with my custom one, or even replace AwsSpringWebRuntimeInitializer to create the necessary bean? I would not like to copy the whole lib so I hope there is a more adequate solution.

can't you set an env property in such a way, so that isCustomRuntime returns false? Then register your own implementation?

But I need to register this only when it's custom runtime

The AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop is final so the logic in the AwsSpringWebRuntimeInitializer won't detect your custom instance. What you can do, is copy the AwsSpringWebCustomRuntimeEventLoop put it in the same package in your source root and customize it. That way your customized class will be loaded (and thus override) the one from the dependency. However the class is final for a reason so aren't there any other extension points you can hook into?

@M.Deinum Thanks, it worked, unfortunetely there is no way to inject my implementation into their code.

You shouldn't need to as your implementation overrides theirs already due to being first on the classpath.

@M.Deinum Sorry, for confusing, I did manage to do it, your solution worked well. "unfortunetely there is no way to inject my implementation into their code" was related to your question - "However the class is final for a reason so aren't there any other extension points you can hook into?"
